# Does this code use recursion?(quicksort)

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

im not that familiar with the concept of recursion, and im not sure if these codes have recursion in them or use recursion.

```
def quickSort(alist):
    quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)

def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
    if first<last:

        splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

        quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)
        quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)


def partition(alist,first,last):
    pivotvalue = alist[first]

    leftmark = first+1
    rightmark = last

    done = False
    while not done:

        while leftmark <= rightmark and \
              alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
            leftmark = leftmark + 1

        while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and \
              rightmark >= leftmark:
            rightmark = rightmark -1

        if rightmark < leftmark:
            done = True
        else:
            temp = alist[leftmark]
            alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
            alist[rightmark] = temp

    temp = alist[first]
    alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
    alist[rightmark] = temp


    return rightmark
```

if it's included, pointing out where it is would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a recursive function is one that calls itself within itself.

Furthermore, the only function that does this in your code is the second one:

```
def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
    if first<last:

        splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

        quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)  # Calls itself here
        quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)   # and here
```

So, the second function is [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29); the other two are not.

---

Note: As @Sean said in the comment below, the definition I gave for recursion is a very simplified one.  There are other code structures (such as two or more methods alternately calling one another) that can be classified as using recursion.  For a complete overview of recursion, please see the link I gave above.

Comment: Technically that definition is not complete. You can have mutual recursion wherein two (or more!) methods alternately call each other.

Comment: @Sean - I know, I thought about that.  However, I didn't want to overwhelm the OP who is clearly new to this.  I'll mention it though.